# Javascript - Odds scraping from unibet - how decript hascode

Tags: javascript, decode, hashcode

https://www.unibet.fr/zones/mainheadlines.json?pageId=200
Hello how can i decrypt the hashCode (its the oddd)

> [{"selectionId":"216733072_1","name":"Monaco","idfolifestate":null,"idfoselectionsuspensiontype":null,"currentPriceUp":"9","currentPriceDown":"2","currentHandicap":"","currentLowerBand":"","currentUpperBand":"","currentHomeScoreLine":null,"currentAwayScoreLine":null,"hadValue":"H","selPercentage":4,"hashCode":792990791},

It's to have the real odds (it's 5.50 here)

792990791 => 5.50

https://static.unibet.fr/app-prod-v6.3.186.js

The only way that i can found the odd it's to do an dictionary with webbrowser

Hello sorry for my bad English How to decode the hashcode from the first website "hashCode":792990791 How to decode it to have 5.50 (it's the real value) I have found an javascript that contains "hashCode" i think that this script decode the hash but i don't understand how

Comment: I can insert a CD-ROM and from the contents, calculate an MD5 hash-code. You cannot reconstruct the CD-ROM from this tiny amount of data. You *could* however, use this small piece of data to uniquely identify this CD-ROM inside a library of many others. I would not expect to be able to turn this 9 digit number into the actual odds without access to their database.

Comment: It's quite unusual to see a field called `hashCode` which contains only an encrypted value of a simple numeric field.  Are you sure that's where the odds are, and that, for instance it's not `(currentPriceUp + currentPriceDow) / currentPriceDown`?  (I know little about betting odds, so this may be way off base, but a few more examples should help demonstrate its likeliness.)

Comment: we cann't do it with this script : https://static.unibet.fr/app-prod-v6.3.186.js ?

Comment: thanks you Scott Sauyet your observation will help me a lot because i don't need to have exactly the good odd just around them it's good !

Comment: they don't give the odd but an approximation ^^

i have found  that the hashcode it's the odd because when i search the same odd for an other match i found the same hashcode

Answer (score 0):

No decoding necessary just some simple math: `(currentPriceUp / currentPriceDown) + 1`

You can thing of `currentPriceUp` as the stake, and `currentPriceDown` as the payout.